# Gatsby wrapPageElement causing elements to render twice

Tags: gatsby

Using wrapPageElement in `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` is causing header and footer elements to render twice.

***gatsby-browser.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import PageLayout from './src/components/layout/PageLayout';

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  // Wraps every page in a component
  return <PageLayout {...props}>{element}</PageLayout>;
};
```

***gatsby-ssr.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import PageLayout from './src/components/layout/PageLayout';

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  // Wraps every page in a component
  return <PageLayout {...props}>{element}</PageLayout>;
};
```

**PageLayout.tsx**

```
const PageLayout: FC =() =>{
   return (
     <PageWrapper>
         <Header/>
         <Footer/>
     </PageWrapper>
  );
};
```

I also have errors in these files on the return line but can't see what is causing the error

> JSHint: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.(W030)

Is there any alternatives or known causes of this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your pages should also be containing a `Layout` component wrapper so the header and the footer are added by the page itself plus the `wrapPageElement`.

If you need to use `wrapPageElement`, you should get rid of the `Layout` in the pages, otherwise, remove the `wrapPageElement`.

In your pages you can do:

```
const SomePage=()=>{
  return <>
   <div>Some dummy content</div>
  <>
}
```

Instead of wrapping it with the `Layout` component.

Regarding the other warning:

> JSHint: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
> expression.(W030)

It's impossible to guess with the provided details or seeing the whole app, could be anywhere but certainly it is not caused by the `wrapPageElement` wrapper.

Comment: So I have a wrapper already around my header and footer. I use that wrapper in my wrapPageElement function. So for ```gatsby develop``` this stops the double render. But in ```gatsby build``` I get the "you must wrap your application in an <SSRProvider> " warnings

Comment: Can you edit your question with the needed details of your implementation?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: This is odd because `PageLayout` is wrapping the whole application + adds a header and footer, this is not gonna work... I don't know the reason behind that but using React (and Gatsby) router you can keep the header and the footer intact refreshing the internal content